# Find first element of numpy ndarray of unknown shape

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

Is there an easy way to pull out the first item of an ndarray if you don't know the shape of the array?

For example. Given the following array:

```
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]])

>>> [[[ 1  2  3  4]
      [ 5  6  7  8]
      [ 9 10 11 12]]]
```

I want to get `1` without assuming I know the shape of this array is 1*3*4.

I am also interested in minimizing the memory and cpu requirements of the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to get a flattened view of the ndarray and then *chain* it with `[0]` to extract the first element, like so -

```
arr.ravel()[0]
```

Please note that [`.flatten()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) would create a copy, so in terms of memory might not be a great idea, even though it would still give you the right result.

One way to check whether an operation is creating a `copy` or `view` is by checking for memory sharing flag with [`np.may_share_memory`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html), like so -

```
In [15]: np.may_share_memory(arr.flatten(),arr)
Out[15]: False # Not sharing memory means a copy

In [16]: np.may_share_memory(arr.ravel(),arr)
Out[16]: True # Sharing memory means a view
```

It seems, one can also use [`.flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) to get a view.

---

Seems there is an elegant alternative in [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) -

```
np.take(arr,0) # Input array is arr, 0 is the index position
```

Comment: `ravel` will also create a copy if the array's memory layout isn't C-contiguous. It's better to use `arr.flat[0]` or `arr.take(0)`, depending on whether you want a NumPy scalar or an ordinary Python scalar. Those options never require a copy.

Comment: @user2357112 Hmm, that's really useful information. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way that I've found so far it to use the [`item()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) method:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]])
>>> arr.item(0)
1
```

Be aware, though, that it converts the value to a Python object, so the performance might depend on the data type and on which version of Python you are using.

```
>>> type(arr.item(0))
int
```

The next fastest is `arr.flat[0]`.  It has the advantage of returning a numpy type.

```
>>> arr.flat[0]
1
>>> type(arr.flat[0])
numpy.int64
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [flatten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy.ndarray.flatten) then take element `[0]`

```
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]])

>>> [[[ 1  2  3  4]
      [ 5  6  7  8]
      [ 9 10 11 12]]]

arr.flatten()[0]

>>> 1
```

Comment: `np.flatten` isn't great in terms of performance and memory usage, since it returns a copy of the array rather than a view

Answer (score 1):

The above answers will work. However, you could also use:

```
arr.reshape(-1)[0]
```